# Status code of the method

Tags: java, http, get, httpclient

I am executing following sample program of httpclient of "GET" method.

```
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;

    public class TestMethodStatuscode {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.USER_AGENT,
     "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
     //client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

    GetMethod get = new GetMethod("http://de.mg40.mail.yahoo.com/neo/launch?.rand=80g4u84m26ifl");
    //get_siteurl.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
    client.executeMethod(get);
    System.out.println("Status code: "+get.getStatusCode());
    //System.out.println(get.getResponseBodyAsString());
    get.releaseConnection();
}
```

}

output:- Status code: 200

The url I am trying to fetch is some url which I get during process of login to `yahoo.de` email account (login to `yahoo.de` did not work for me so was trying this code). If I enable wireshark (filter-http or `(http.request.method == POST or http.request.method == GET)` and then type this url in browser , press enter and finally I notice in wireshark that the return code of the above url is `302` which means it is redirected.

Also when I run my program and check in wireshark, I see that method returns the code `302`. So my queston is why it is giving me `200` as a statuscode as output and not `302` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/GetMethod.html):

> GetMethods will follow redirect requests from the http server by default. This behavour can be disabled by calling setFollowRedirects(false).

Answer (score 1):

You probably follow redirects set to true.  You can get this with the `getFollowRedirects()` method.  If that returns true, it will automatically follow redirects. You can set it to false to remove that behavior.